# download file from S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, role

I have launched an ec2 instance with IAM role and have associated following policy with IAM role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::/testbucket/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I keep on getting access denied when I try to download the file using aws cli from within ec2-instance.

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket testbucket --key file_name file_name
```

I get message 'allowed' when I simulate the policy and perform action on the objects in bucket. And I can see correct instance profile is attached with instance when I access http://169.254.254/latest-metadata/iam/info

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overlooking a small typo.

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::/testbucket/*"
```

There should be no `/` before bucket name. Changed it and everything was fine.

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
```